# Looking for better theming guide for Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

Having checked the documentation at Drupal.org, I am looking for a concise guide for theming drupal 7 as contained in "Pro Drupal Development" for 5 and 6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EmmaJane Hogbin, who co-authored Front End Drupal, the best book that I know about theming Drupal 6, has a blog on her website ( http://www.designtotheme.com/blog ) that is beginning to cover Drupal 7 theming. Her new sitebuilding extravaganza course for Drupal 7 theming is in session, so it's too late to sign-up for that.

Chris Shattuck has a great subscription video instruction website called Build a Module, which has a section on Drupal theming: http://buildamodule.com/

Packt Publishing lists an upcoming book (Jine 2011) by Rick Sheves called Drupal 7 Themes: RAW.